# Apache Vysper - XMPPServer ClassNotFoundException

Tags: classnotfoundexception, apache-vysper

I have a short question. I want to create a XMPP server with `Apache Vysper`. But when I try to create a server:

```
XMPPServer server = new XMPPServer("myserver.com");
```

I get a `ClassNotFoundException` on this line, although the class is imported correctly.

Can Somebody help me out?

Thanks :)

Here the Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/vysper/xmpp/server/XMPPServer
    at de.seba.vyspertest.App.main(App.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.vysper.xmpp.server.XMPPServer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: It could be helpful to see the relevant part of your error trace.

Comment: I only have this one line in my main method...

Comment: I meant your output, where the ClassNotFoundException appears. It would be helpful to see the first 10-15 lines of this.

Comment: Is your classpath set up correctly? (do you have the Vysper jar on the classpath?)

Comment: I added the vysper-core dependency in my pom.xml file. And I can find XMPPServer.class in the Vysper-core-0.7.jar within the Maven Dependencies directory. It is defintively there...

Comment: Hmmm... seems to be a very weird bug in version 0.7 ... if I use version 0.6 it works... very strange :D

Comment: :-) Just brainstorming here, but do you have the correct version in the pom.xml dependency? You could also double check this here: http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=apache+vysper

Comment: yes, I got it from there ;)